# Devexpress DataLayoutControl - how to add controls

Tags: devexpress

Is there any way to add or remove controls to/from a DataLayoutControl in DevExpress without deleting all the existing controls? If so, how? I'm using Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 0):

DataLayoutControl manages layout items containing child controls. If you need to create a new item, create a new [LayoutControlItem](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraLayout.LayoutControlItem.class) as shown in this class description.

To remove a layout item, use the [LayoutControl.Remove](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraLayout.LayoutControl.Remove.overloads) method.

The [Items](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraLayout.LayoutControl.Items.property) help article should be also useful since it illustrates how to operate layout items and controls.